# Cannot connect to SQL Server from another PC

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server, connection, sql-server-2000

I am using windows XP SP2 and SQL Server 2000. I can successfully connect to a database from the host computer via 127.0.0.1 and also with the local IP (which is 192.168.1.6).

But when when I try to connect to that database from another PC via 192.168.1.6, it doesn't work.

- I tried to allow ports in the firewall and it still didn't work. I also tried turning the firewall off and it still didn't work.
- I can ping 192.168.1.6 successfully from other computers.
- I tried WampServer which worked.
- I also did some TCP/IP settings which Microsoft asked me to do and it still didn't work.

I think it has something to do with SQL Server permission and/or the listening IP, since the error message says that the database does not exist or that access is denied (but I know that the database exists).

How should I continue my error searching process?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from SQL Server Enterprise manager/ Query Analyser or any .NET application?

Comment: Did you enable the TCP/IP in the "SQL Server Configuration Manager"?

Comment: in the database... who is allowed to connect? I don't know how it is in MSSQL but in mySQL you have to explicitly set the user and database to accept connections from other IP addresses.

Comment: I am trying to connect SQL Server. I want to connect to a specific database. 

And yes I did enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager. 

I allowed two users to connect to the database that is "sa" and "acclogin" but I have no idea about the IP thing you are talking about.

Comment: Well normally you have to allow users to connect from outside the server. Might help: http://www.bodhost.com/forum/windows-dedicated-server/3276-configure-mssql-allow-remote-connections-windows-dedicated-hosting.html

Comment: Thank You DemonWareXT, Let me try these steps with MSSQL 2005. I will tell you if I get it correct. Thank you all for your help.